# What is <<<_END?

Tags: php, heredoc

I'm new to PHP and don't understand what the point of `<<<_END` is. Could someone please explain when this should be used? I've looked at various examples and they all seem to have HTML embedded within them. But I can use HTML without the `<<<_END` tags, so why should I use them? I tried searching the manual, but I keep finding the `end()` method for arrays.

Comment: Please show the code in question. You are probably looking for "heredoc notation"

Comment: I've seen it in various places, but here's a link to one example http://lpmj.net/examples.php?c=20&e=5&x=php

Comment: Funny thing I use PHP for more than 5 years now and I never knew this exists.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's the start of a [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). you can do:

```
$data = <<< _END

You can write anything you want in between the start and end

_END;
```

`_END` can be just about anything. You could put `EOF` or `STUFF`. as long as you use the same thing at the start and the finish.

Comment: Thanks. So the only reason you'd use heredocs would be to write multiple lines (for clarity)?

Comment: It is also useful for writing large strings of text without the need to escape any characters.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept the answer in a few minutes (can't do it atm)

Comment: Heredocs are basically multi-line double-quoted strings, without the need for the quotes.

Answer (score 3):

This signifies the beginning of a [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) (a multi-line string that allows you to use quotation marks in the middle, unescaped) that ends when you encounter the `_END`

It can be useful to define HTML in one of these if the goal is to assign it to a variable or pass it to a function rather than printing it to the web server immediately.

Answer (score 2):

That syntax is called [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
<<<_END
some text
_END
```

Basically, it's a way of writing a string without worrying about escaping quotes and so on.

As you've mentioned, it doesn't really provide a lot of benefit over other string formats - although, it does mean you can write a block of HTML without escaping out of PHP with ?> <?php

It also isn't too popular as its use generally goes against the practice of seperating content from logic by embedding the content in the middle of your script.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

It allows you to echo out a block of text (just the same as with `echo "words";`), but without using the beginning/ending quotes, and without having to escape contained double quotes. Read the manual link above for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). It's just a way of defining a string.