# Parse error on file when trying to include navbar page

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

```
<?php

echo <<< END
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--

-->
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Nav</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
         <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="M.html">Clarity</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>


_END;

?>
```

I am trying to include a navbar at the top of every page within my web application. I have created this file in order to include other pages to display the navbar. This doesn't work however, as I continue to get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting variable
>   (T_VARIABLE) or heredoc end (T_END_HEREDOC) or ${
>   (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES) or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the following resource: [What is <<<_END?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675814/what-is-end)

The starting line

```
echo <<< END
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
```

Should be:

```
echo <<< _END
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
```

Answer (score 0):

**remove underscore and You probably have spaces after the terminator.**

```
END;[space]
```

hit enter after `END;`

**EDIT:**
 It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon.

check here for more
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Why would that make a difference?

Comment: I'm still not sure why this would make a difference. Is there any documentation that states this needs to be done or the reasons behind it?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a better way of doing this is like this:

```
<?php

// Some PHP code here
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--

-->
<html>
<head>

    <title>Nav</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
     <!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">

        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="M.html">Clarity</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
<?php

// Continuing with PHP code
```